# Add circle on Bokeh image

Tags: image, geometry, bokeh

I'm working with Bokeh and I want to add a circle on a specific position on my image.
For the moment, I create my image like this :

```
img = image(image=[data], 
    x_range=[0, x_range], 
    y_range=[0, y_range], 
    x=x, 
    y=y, 
    dw=dw,
    dh=dh,
    tools=TOOLS,
    palette=["Greys-9"],
    title=title,
    plot_width=plot_width,
    plot_height=plot_height,
)   
circle(x=10,y=10,radius=100,fill_color="#df1c1c",line_color="#df1c1c")

resources = Resources("inline")

plot_script, plot_div = components(img, resources)

html_script = encode_utf8(plot_script)
html_div = encode_utf8(plot_div)

hold()

figure()

return html_script, html_div
```

and send this to my HTML page.

The problem is that the circle is not on the final display. Maybe on background ? I don't know...

I tryed add function, add_glyph function, add_layout... None of these are functionnal!

Thanks for helping guys

Comment: `add_glyph` and `add_layout` are fairly low level function, part of the "objects" API, it's probably not what you want. When are you calling `circle` ? You should call it after `hold` (so that it goes on the existing plot) and you don't need the call to figure at all.

Comment: Also, you need to put the call to `components` last. If you put the call to `circle` after you call `components` you've already generated the output without the circle...

Comment: Actualy, it's what I did (put the circle creation before the components call). Sorry for my unclear message. Let me edit it.
Anyway, I tryied what you said, still don't work...

Comment: Oh, this is a small bug. Bokeh basically scatters every glyph in a vectorized fashion. You can give some properties as "single numbers" and Bokeh will do the right thing but apparently if you give *all* of them (as you have done) Bokeh gets confused. Try giving at least one of `x`, `y` and `radius` as single element lists, e.g. `x = [10]`

Comment: Can you file an issue on the Bokeh GitHub issue tracker about this?

Comment: Oh damm yes it's working !!! Thanks you so much !!! 
I'll file the issue !
Thanks again !

Comment: Update: this issue has been fixed, and the original code should now also work.

Answer (score 0):

The above code did not work due to a bug in Bokeh. However, the bug has since been fixed, and that code and code similar to it will function as expected.